# Prevent phpQuery newDocument() from making changes

Tags: php, phpquery

I've noticed that when I initialize phpQuery using `phpQuery::newDocument($html)`, there are significant changes made to the HTML passed to that method.

I took a look at the class and saw that it is making some changes to the document intentionally by using `phpQuery::createDocumentWrapper()`.

After looking at the API, I wasn't able to find any information on this, and I would rather not change phpQuery itself.

**How can I prevent phpQuery from changing the HTML I pass to the `newDocument` method?**

Answer (score 2):

Phpquery isn't making those changes, libxml is. And those changes are the result of it fixing your malformed html in order to be able to parse it properly. So, to answer your question, you can't.